On-premise Edge Transport Server Open Ports
With the setup of an Exchange Server, Microsoft recommends using an Edge Transport Server for filtering and security. The Edge Transport Server is to be placed into a DMZ/outside the LAN.
After installing the Edge Transport role on Windows Server 2019 a port scan was performed and it was discovered ports, 80, 443, 1194, 1801, 2103, 2105, 2107 were automatically opened on the Edge server as a result of the installation.
My question is does these open ports pose a threat/risk? Given the fact that the Edge Transport role is operating in a DMZ and if an external port scan was to be performed it will scan the Edge Transport Server not the router/firewall.
I am sure Microsoft is aware of this and would not design a server with any security flaws but I just want to confirm.
Nothing was tried and more security was expected
